# How can I bind a dynamic-length List<> in a Razor/.NET Core PageModel, without relying on JavaScript to re-index each input?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a form in which a user can supply an arbitrary-length list of `<DateTime, int>` pairs. It is represented like so:

```csharp
List<ItemsPerDay> ItemsPerDayList = new List<ItemsPerDay>();
```

```csharp
public class ItemsPerDay {
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

```
<tbody>
  @{ var i = 0; } 
  @foreach (var _ in Model.ItemsPerDayList) {
    <tr>
      <td><input asp-for="ItemsPerDayList[i].Date" type="date" /></td>
      <td><input asp-for="ItemsPerDayList[i].Amount" /></td>
      <td><a class="remove">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    i++; 
  }
</tbody>
```

**The issue:**

The user is able to add/remove rows as they need. However, the property binding relies on the pairs being properly indexed. If, for example, you remove the first item, the list now begins at `[1]` and the property binding does not work; `ItemsPerDayList` is posted as `null`.

**My current workaround:**

I've had to use some JavaScript to make sure the indexes always remain correct. This works but isn't optimal.

```
function reIndexItemRows() {
  $("table > tbody > tr").each(function(idx) {
    $(this).find("input[type=date]").attr({
      "data-val": true,
      "data-val-required": "The Date field is required.",
      id: `ItemsPerDayList_${idx}__Date`,
      name: `ItemsPerDayList[${idx}].Date`
    });

    $(this).find("input[type=number]").attr({
      "data-val": true,
      "data-val-required": "The Amount field is required.",
      id: `ItemsPerDayList_${idx}__Amount`,
      name: `ItemsPerDayList[${idx}].Amount`
    });
  });
}
```

**The question:**

What is the appropriate way to represent this model on the front-end, such that I don't have to rely on JavaScript to groom the form each time a row is added or removed?

**NOTE:** I am **not** doing any updates, therefore the indexes are not necessary. Upon submission, any existing pairs are deleted, and the form-submitted pairs are inserted.

Comment: You could re-render the entire list every time it's modified.  That's the only other way I know of to do this.

Comment: Since you use "foreach" loop, do you really need the indexes? What if you try something like this <td><input asp-for="_.Date" type="date" /></td> ?

Comment: @Vladimir That doesn't work. Hypothetically if it were valid I imagine it would suffer the same consequence, as you're still binding the input to one item specifically. The bottleneck as far as I'm aware is the formdata markup.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is necessary for adjusting index. You can add events to adjust the index when submitting the form.

Add a event on **Remove**. Here is the form.

```
<form  method="post" id="myform">
<table>
    <tbody>
        @{ var i = 0; }
        @foreach (var _ in Model.ItemsPerDayList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input asp-for="ItemsPerDayList[i].Date" type="date" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="ItemsPerDayList[i].Amount" /></td>
                <td><a class="remove" onclick="remove(this)" >Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
            i++;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="name" value="submit" />
</form>

<button id="add" onclick="add()" class="btn-primary">add</button>
```

Before submitting the form, javascript iterates each row and modify the index.

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $('#myform').submit(function () {
        var i = 0;
        $("tbody> tr ").each(function () {
            $(this).find("td input[name$='Date']").attr("name", "ItemsPerDayList[" + i + "].Date");
            $(this).find("td input[name$='Amount']").attr("name", "ItemsPerDayList[" + i + "].Amount");
            i++
        })
        // ...
        return true; // return false to cancel form action
    });

    function remove(e) {
        $(e).parent().parent().remove()
    }
    function add() {
        $('tbody').append('<tr><td> <input name="ItemsPerDayList[i].Date" type="date" /></td ><td><input name="ItemsPerDayList[i].Amount" /><td><a class="remove" onclick="remove(this)">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    }
</script>

 }
```

Then, I can get the all data from front-end.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but unfortunately it didn't steer me any closer at the time. The code you've provided in your answer performs the same thing I'd already noted in the **Current Workaround** section of my question.